# Create an ordered Index in sqlite db using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm defining a table in SQLAlchemy using the declarative API. It's got a foreign key which I'd like to index. My question is: how do I define the index created from `master_ref` to be an **ASC** or **DESC** index (without resorting to doing it manually with SQL)?

```
class Item(Base):
    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    master_ref = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('master.id'), nullable=True, index=True)
    value = Column(REAL)
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#index-api) of SqlAlchemy, an alternative way to create the index would be:

```
class Item(Base):
    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    master_ref = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('master.id'))
    value = Column(REAL)
    Index('ix_name', master_ref)
```

but I cannot find any reference on how to define the ASC or DESC anywhere.

Comment: Note that the proper way is to pass the `Index` in `__table_args__` if defining it in the class body, though your example would also work due to using the actual `Column` object in defining the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a *functional index*, as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#functional-indexes):

> Functional Indexes
>
> Index supports SQL and function expressions, as supported by the
>   target backend. To create an index against a column using a **descending**
>   value, the `ColumnElement.desc()` modifier may be used:
>
> ```
> from sqlalchemy import Index
>
> Index('someindex', mytable.c.somecol.desc())
> ```

And likewise for an *ascending* value, use the `ColumnElement.asc()` modifier.